# SImulate a mouse move in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I would like to know how to simulate a mouse movement in a widget.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QCursor allows you to set position:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcursor.html

Most QWidget methods should allow you to find the cursor in one way or another.

edit: so for example

```
cursor = mywidget.getCursor() # or event.getCursor()
pos = cursor.pos()
cursor.setPos((pos[0]+1, pos[1]+1))
```

that should move it by 1 pixel on each direction